# Find All Visitor's IP Addresses in Centos

Tags: logging, centos, ip

i have Centos VPS, i am hosting many websites. normally i use statcounter to track visitors but i think statcounter can not track all requests made to my websites. is there anyway to Find All Visitor's IP Addresses in Centos server, is there any log file that contains all IP addresses of visitors, where is this? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to learn active connected users :

```
netstat -n | grep ':80'
```

or if you want to find history of connected users you should check your web server's log files.
e.g.

```
/var/log/httpd/access_log
```

for apache